# Движок для высоконагруженного сайта

Tags: cms

Доброго Вам времени суток))) Есть один вопрос: собираюсь создать высоконагруженный сайт, что-то вроде социальной сети. Какой движок посоветуете, да и нужен ли он вообще???

Comment: мозг + любой среверный язык = успех :)

Comment: Учту)))

Comment: Движок движком, но когда Вы сами мастерите то это будет намного лучше, хоть движки и облегчают жизнь, но всеже.

Answer (score 4):

Для социальной и вообще сайта,можно использовать [LiveStreet](http://livestreetcms.com/)

Ну или Drupal,если есть желание.А разработка собственного движка сулит проблемы,в основном безопасности,в готовых cms как никак,команда разработчиков заделывают дыры,да и зачем изобретать велосипед)

Comment: Ну принципе да.

Comment: Но для старых(готовых) и дыры отыскиваются скорее, или есть известные уже, если движок не up-to-date и т.п.

Answer (score 4):

1. Поставить цель
2. Иметь знания
3. Запастись терпением
4. Иметь много времени на реализацию
5. Пиво и музыка сопутсвуют работе (если работа проходит дома)
6. Садимся и пишим код сами!

Плюсы очевидны.

1. Модули и прочие реализации дорабатывать проще под собственные нужды
2. Всегда будет интрига и интерес таких граждан как тут зависают(на чем написан и т.д.)
3. Свой код всегда радует глаз
4. Любая задача всегда будет реализована а не то что я не нашел определенного модуля или компонента ну и х... с ним
5. Свой код вегда можно реализовать у кого-то другого срубив на этом денег и отбив пиво, потраченое терпение и оправдать свое время естественно в $$$

P.S. ИМХО

Comment: 5ый и 6ой пункт полностью поддерживаю, сам такой же :)

Answer (score 4):

Я бы посоветовал писать самому, вместо использования готового решения.. Правда вот писать с нуля, смысло большого нету.. Если у вас нет своих наработок, разработанной архитектуры (оставшейся от прошлого проекта), то на реализацию проекта уйдет огромная куча времени, и результат может быть совсем не положительный. Я бы посоветовал вам использовать Фрэймворки(Symfony, Zend и др.) В результате у вас появляется возможность использовать уже напсанные либы (тот же юзер менежмент) и вы не тратите время на создание архитектуры проекта, а сразу начинаете творить ваш высоконагруженный сайт :)

Answer (score 3):

Однозначно самописный, работал с такими при посещаемости 100к в сутки. Так же использовался Sphinx и memcache

Answer (score 2):

Писать «все с нуля» — как-то сильно по-пионерски. Есть уже много хорошего кода, переписывать который имеет смысл, разве что, в качестве упражнений. Но высоконагруженные ресурсы, если мы говорим не о синтетической нагрузке на стенде, как правило, имеют другое применение, чем чисто упражнения.

Опять же, редкий ресурс получит свои 100500k pageviews прямо вот сразу. Поэтому есть вариант сделать его на том, что удобно, просто отмечая про себя «вот если это будет тормозить, то я потом тут сделаю вот так-то». И останавливаться на переделки только, когда представления о том, как все можно смасштабировать не оказывается.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте Zend, symfony или любой другой популярный MVC framework. Позволит разработать систему практически с нуля как вам надо + можно внести свои навороты аля кеширование и т.д.